# nginx does not allow access by subnet

Tags: nginx

I have the following conf file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf. I am trying to limit access to /path1 and /path2 url to /16 subnet range. When I try to access froma  machine in the subnet I get 404 only when I comment out/ remove the block can I access it but then it is accessible from anywhere. What I am doing wrong ... any pointers is appreciated ..

```
  server {
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    # Enable compression, this will help if you have for instance advagg module
    # by serving Gzip versions of the files.
    gzip_static on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/app.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app.error.log;

    listen 9000;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;       ## <-- Your domain.
    root /opt/app;  ## <-- Path to your Drupal files.

    location / {
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
             rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm-www.sock; ## <-- location of the PHP-FPM socket
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
            return 403;



 # as Subversion or Git to store control files.

    location ~ (^|/)\. {

            return 403;

    }

    location ~* \.(conf|config)$ {

            deny all;

    }



#  location /path1 {

     # allow 10.5.0.0/16;

     # deny all;

  #  }



    location /path2 {

      allow 10.5.0.0/16;

      deny all;

    }





#Expire rules



# Media: images, icons, video, audio

location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$ {

   expires 1M;

   add_header Cache-Control "max-age=2592000 public";

}



# CSS and Javascript

location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {

   expires 6M;

   add_header Cache-Control "max-age=15552000 public";

}



location ~* \.(?:html|htm|php|cgi|pl)$ {

    expires 2h;

    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=7200 public";

}



}



#HTTP redirect to HTTPS

server {

listen 80;

server_name 0.0.0.0;

return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}
```

Comment: location /path2 {

      allow 10.5.0.0/16;

      deny all;

    }

Comment: http://<qualifieddomain>/path1 ...

Comment: hi, there is nothing after path1 ... path1 corresponds to a resource which is under root / .... what im after is why my location block which has allow from a particular subnet doesnt work ...when i put the location block only its like only the deny rule takes effect and not the allow rule ...which suggests that the location block is being used when requests come in for /path1 and /path2 ...

Comment: Right I see, I'm sorry I can see that in the question now. I've removed my other comments as they don't help given that the info is in the question